# What the Bug with flex slider; after event fires on hover when opacity of slides is animated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I have been trying to animate opacity of slides in flex slider and observed that the `after` function gets executed on hover over slides. Here is the jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqwk6Lp2/

Pressing right arrow icon in bottom thumbnail slider and then hovering over any thumnail fires the `after` function of flex slider and even takes wrong value of `slider.currentSlide`. This can be seen in the console, as I have logged output on `after` event. Live demo again if jsfiddle goes down:

```js
$('#carousel').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  animationLoop: false,
  slideshow: false,
  itemWidth: 210,
  itemMargin: 5,
  asNavFor: '#slider',
  after: function(slider) {
    console.log("after carousel");
    console.log(slider.currentSlide);
    //flexLazy(undefined, $("#flex-carousel-H img")[slider.currentSlide]);
    //flexLazy(undefined, $("#flex-carousel-H img")[slider.currentSlide - 1]);
    //flexLazy(undefined, $("#flex-carousel-H img")[slider.currentSlide + 1]);
  }
});

$('#slider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  animationLoop: false,
  slideshow: false,
  sync: "#carousel",
  after: function(slider) {
    console.log("after slider");
    console.log(slider.currentSlide);

  }

});
```

```css
#carousel img {
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}
#carousel img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/flexslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/jquery.flexslider.min.js"></script>

<!-- Place somewhere in the <body> of your page -->
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

The only thing that cause this bug is:

```
#carousel img {  
    opacity: .5;       
    transition: opacity .5s ease-out;  
}
#carousel img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Question:**

1. Why does the `after` event fire on hovering over any thumbnail when right arrow icon is pressed in thumbnail slider?
2. In Firefox dev tools all events assigned to an element are shown in `ev` black icon. When I click on it I see no `mouseover`, `mouseout` event registered. If no hover event exist then why does `after` function get executed on hover?
3. I am very much afraid that something's wrong with `MSPointerUp` event. But isn't that for Internet explorer only?

P.S: This is really an annoying bug. It took me a lot of time to pin down that opacity transition was causing this bug. I have a lot of lazy load stuff that depends upon after event :-(

Comment: I've just run into the same issue. Did you solve this at all?

Comment: I ended up using the 'before' callback instead. It did not fire unexpected events on hover.